# Azure, DocumentDB cannot save POCO object as a document

Tags: azure, poco, azure-cosmosdb

I have serious problem with MS Azure DocumentDB.

I Know it's in pre-realese only, but as I know it is said that it is possible to save Dynamic and POCO objects as a documents. When I save dynamic object it works just fine (object is added to a collection):

```
     dynamic dynamicObject = new
                             {
                                 testId = "12",
                                 text = "aaa bbb ccc"
                             };
     await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionSelfLink, dynamicObject);
```

However, when I try to add a POCO obejct, it doesnt works (nothing is added to a collection):

```
    public class House
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string HouseId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    ------------------

    House house = new House() {HouseId = "1", Name="TestHouse", Address="asdasdasd"};
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionSelfLink, house);
```

Everything else is the same.

---

EDIT: temp solution is to inherit your POCO class from Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document class.

Comment: I am unable to repro this, It works as expected. Could you post more of your code, or a project that repros this.

Answer (score 1):

as per my comment, can't repro this.
here is my test project:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    House house = new House() { HouseId = "1", Name = "TestHouse", Address = "asdasdasd" };
    Document doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync(col.DocumentsLink, house).Result;

    Console.Write(doc.SelfLink);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  public class House
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string HouseId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
  }
```

results in 1 document created and doc.selfLink being printed to the Console.